# .NET WinForms - DataGridView shaking while changing items' visibility variables which depend on selected grid item

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

So I have grid view where the user can add and remove items. Some options in the UI are hidden by default and shown if the selected item has certain properties enabled. The problem is whenever I switch items by clicking an element with different controls visible the form shakes violently until I release mouse button resulting in multiple selected items in the grid view. This is a very irritating bug and I don't know how to fix it :(

[image: This is what my grid looks like.]

My code if it helps:

```cs
private void executable_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedRows = buttonGrid.SelectedRows;

    if (executable.SelectedIndex != 2)
    {
        pathBrowse.Visible = false;
        path_textbox.Visible = false;
        label10.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        pathBrowse.Visible = true;
        path_textbox.Visible = true;
        label10.Visible = true;
    }

    if (selectedRows != null && selectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        CButton b = (CButton)selectedRows[0].Tag;

        if (b == null) return;

        b.ExecType = executable.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Forms don't "shake", unless maybe if you're changing their `Location` multiple times in rapid succession. If that's happening without your having written code to do it then something is broken. What is actually happening? Is it that those controls being hidden and shown is causing other controls to move? If it's more than that and it's not because something is broken then it's due to code that you haven't shown us. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You probably need to set `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout(false)`, but it's not clear what causes a change in the layout when you toggled the visibility of your Controls. Do you have auto-sizing Containers? Are some of these Controls docked (concurrently)? -- The code snippet you posted doesn't exactly clarify what's happening or what objects you're working with.

Comment: @Jimi my form is auto-sizing. That's what causes it to shake. Will SuspendLayout() work on this context?

Comment: Didn't you test it? Anyway, you probably don't want your Form to auto-size when the visibility of those Controls is toggled. Add them to another Container (e.g., a Panel) which doesn't resize on its content. Nested containers is a standard design feature.